# Ansible playbook : How to get server up or down status

Tags: ansible

I'm designing a dashboard for displaying all servers status(up/down),free RAM,Kernel version,Processor type etc using ansible playbook. Using gather facts,I can get all server parameters easily,but not sure how to get server up/down using playbook. If server is down,ansible cannot connect to server hence 'ping' module cannot used. Please help me. IS there any way to catch the return value if playbook fails for any server ?

The order how ansible connects is 1. Make ssh connection 2.if ssh succeeds, gather facts 3. Execute playbook taks one by one.  If ping is a task inside playbook, control wont even come to that place and ansible would have thrown connection error in step 1 itself.  Please refer below https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ping_module.html

Also,please note My inventory contains many servers and I need to get server status of each of them.

Comment: Why don't you use the shell module, ping the server and register the output?

Comment: `If server is down,ansible cannot connect to server hence 'ping' module cannot used. `..what? why?

Comment: Ansible documentation says using ping module in playbookd doesnt make any sense https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ping_module.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the result of the ping as per comment, or use the wait_for if you want to check a different port:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - wait_for: host=192.168.87.100 port=80 timeout=1
    - debug: msg=ok
```